# How to create a Text type field in db via Hibernate+Java

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I do have a Java Web Applicaiton (struts2, hibernate, beans) + PostreSQL as DB. The task is to save the `base64` encoded text in the db for some specific table. That `base64` is generated from `pdf` file, which is then `ciphered` with a specific algorithm. The `pdf` files <1mb, mostly <300kb.

I did a search and it's suggested to save the base64 as a `Text` field in the DB. It's not problem to create it within the PostgreSQL itself, but I have to create it via a `Model` class + hibernate.

What I did:

Imported `import org.apache.struts2.components.Text;`

Generated getters/setters. Added one row to my `*.hbm.xml` file.

```
<property name="base64signed" column="base64signed" />
```

And I got this error:

> Could not determine type for: org.apache.struts2.components.Text

Comment: placed all annotations at public getter methods and not private

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with this annotation :

```
@Lob(type = LobType.CLOB)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Hibernate supports conversion of org.apache.struts2.components.Text to DB's varchar.

So you store it as LOB or CLOB as mentioned in above

```
@Lob
private Text base64signed;
```

Or you can make it easy by declaring your 'base64signed' field as String, it will take less memory in DB

```
@Column
private String base64signed;
```